# How to set IP Address Restrictions for Management Service in IIS through PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, iis, windows-server-2016, ip-restrictions

I'm looking for a way to script the whole IIS configuration through PowerShell and I've already done most of it. The problem I'm facing right now is how to set '**IP Address Restrictions**' for **Management Service** in IIS.
I know there is a simple way to do it for a domain or a site but my goal is to limit the number of IP's being able to deploy to IIS.

Including screenshot for clarification:
[IIS Management Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I21pP.png)

Comment: what have you tried? what did not work as expected?

Comment: I have no idea on how to add the `mode` and the `requestor` values using PowerShell instead of using UI.

Comment: As stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831792(v=ws.11)#add-allow-or-deny-connection-rule-dialog-box), these only can be configured in IIS manager. Information about requestor are stored in the registry in an encrypted manner, not config file.You can navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WebManagement\Server  to check.

Comment: Thank you @BruceZhang! As I already know the value I want to set up, I looked up it's value in the registry and thanks to that I could include it in my script. Mystery solved!

Answer (score 0):

Following @BruceZhang advice, I've firstly set up the required value using the UI, then looked up the registry 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WebManagement\Server\RemoteRestrictions' and found out the encrypted value for my ip address. From now on setting it up was only a matter of changing the value for this key in the registry through PowerShell script. It works fine, thanks!

`Stop-Service -Name "WMSVC"`

`Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WebManagement\Server" -Name "RemoteRestrictions" -Value /wEZAgAAAAEAAABnAgAAABkBAAAAAAAAABkDAAAAAQAAAC4EA8ADqAMdAx0CAAAALgQD/wP/A/8D/wMAAAB`

`Start-Service -Name "WMSVC"`